# How to return lines, where the last word ending with a consonant letter?

Tags: regex, grep

My regex should return lines, where the last word ending with a consonant letter. 
I write:

```
egrep '[^aeiou]\b$'
```

but it returns only lines, which not ending in a dot.

I'm a beginner in regex, so I will be grateful if you could help me.

For example, my test file:

```
Hello world
Hello world.
London is the capital of GB.
Oslo is the capital of Norway
Oslo is the capital of Norway.
Oslo is not a capital of Ukraine.
```

Now my expression returns:

```
Hello world
Oslo is the capital of Norway
```

But it should return:

```
Hello world
Hello world.
London is the capital of GB.
Oslo is the capital of Norway
Oslo is the capital of Norway.
```

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: It's not clear what should happen to punctuation marks but what you are asking is literally `egrep '[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]$'`.

Comment: Is 'y' a consonant? It's not in my language. (Just curious)

Comment: The letter Y can be regarded as both a vowel and a consonant in English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your regex is that it looks for a letter that is not a vowel but in other side it doesn't necessarily looks for consonants. The `\b` shouldn't be there too. As You want to ignore punctuation marks try the following:

```
egrep '[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]\W*$'
```

`\W` means a character that is not `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

Comment: Thank a lot! I just added upper-case condition: 
egrep '[b-df-hj-np-tv-z|B-DF-HJ-NP-TV-Z]\W*$'

Comment: @ValentynTroian You're welcome. You don't need to add them. Just use `-i` option: `egrep -i ...`. Also a pipe in a character class doesn't mean `OR` it means `|` literally.